# Getting Unicode Data from MS Access output will be " ???????????????????"

Tags: java, connection, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I am using MS Access & MySQL ,in access input this word

- کوردستان ی عیراق  (it's kurdish language using unicode )

my code is :

```
try{
      String path ="src\\Database.accdb";
      Class.forName("sun.jdbc.odbc.JdbcOdbcDriver").newInstance();
      Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(""
              + "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+path);
      Statement s = c.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = s.executeQuery("select * from mytable");
      rs.next();
      jTextArea1.setText(rs.getString(1));

  }catch(Exception ex){
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex.getMessage());

  }
```

with access the output is    `??????????????`

but with  MYSQL and the output is کوردستان ی عیراق

Why ??
thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Reading Unicode data from an Access database using JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1467412/reading-unicode-data-from-an-access-database-using-jdbc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to get data from an MS Access db and you don't need to run complex queries, you might want to check out the [Jackcess](http://jackcess.sourceforge.net/) project, which is a native, cross-platform Java API for opening MS Access files.  it doesn't currently have support for running SQL queries, but it *does* give you access to all the data without going through the (flaky) jdbc-odbc bridge.  it also has support for looking up data using indexes (via an IndexCursor).

(disclaimer, i am the primary author).

Comment: It's too late for accepting, forgive me I didn't see it maybe because your answer was two days later :)

Answer (score 1):

You should set a appropriate charset for the properties when you try to establish the connection, e.g.:

```
java.util.Properties prop = new java.util.Properties();
prop.put("charSet", "UTF8"); // Not tested..
Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection(
           "jdbc:odbc:Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; DBQ="+path, prop);
```

Look into the documentation for the [JDBC-ODBC Bridge](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/guide/jdbc/bridge.html) for further details

Comment: Thanks but steal don't working, Sorry for forgetting  I tried Properties before .

Answer (score 0):

From microsoft forums:

```
If your connection character set is utf8, then you should run this query right 
after connecting to DB:

SET NAMES 'utf8'; 

Also your DB and tables and columns should have utf8_general_ci or other type of 
utf8 collation.
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks @Harlandraka, try open MS-Access there is no way to make a CELL 'utf8'.